# how to use validation rules exists for image upload field in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation, laravel-request

I use Laravel 5

in Update,Create Request files

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'image' => 'required', 
        'description' => 'required', 
        'link' => 'required', 

    ];
}
```

but update request needs change image rule because if user modify record image is not required.

I think only exists or not null image, is enough.

Answer (score 1):

What about validating image in **Laravel** way?

place this code in controller

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'image' => 'image',
        //other rules
    ];
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-image

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'image' => 'required_without:id|image',
        //other rules
    ];
}
```

**Explanation:**
Most probably if you are creating new record, id value is not present (by default it is auto-assigned by DataBase), but in case of edit or update id will be present in request (by default record is found by id value) and **image** is not required
refer to  https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-required-without

Answer (score 0):

You can create `UpdateRequest` with the following rules:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'description' => 'required', 
        'link' => 'required', 
    ];
}
```

and use this request for updating Image and create `StoreRequest` that will extend from `UpdateRequest` with the following rules:

```
public function rules()
{
    return array_merge(parent::rules(), [
        'image' => 'required', 
    ]);
}
```

and use this request for adding new image